# Сомневаюсь, можно ли назвать выделенные фрагменты придаточными сравнениями

Tags: синтаксис

(1) *Спать он больше не мог, есть он больше не мог, а если он и садился за стол, то только потому, что воображал, **будто за этим же столом сидит и она**.*

(2) *Но он был слишком серьезным человеком, чтобы подумать, **будто это было сделано ему назло**.*

Надо отталкиваться наверное от глаголов *воображал* и *подумать*, или нет? Придаточные дополнительные?

Спасибо!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Это СПП с **придаточными изъяснительными** (союзная связь), в которых ЧТО - нейтральный союз, ЧТОБЫ - союз с модальным значением (возможность, желание, достоверность, сомнение), БУДТО - союз **со значением недостоверности**.

**Примеры:**

Я заметил, что он нервничает. Он воображает, будто у него талант. Старайся, чтобы буквы были ровными. Сомнительно, чтобы он согласился.

**Похожие предложения:**

1) **приместоименно-изъяснительные** ("вмещающие", для связи используются союзы/союзные слова): Я согласен с тем, что  основные трудности еще впереди. Это говорит о том, насколько плохо подготовлен эксперимент. Утро началось с того, что они поссорились.

2)  **местоименно-определительные** (обязательная местоименная пара того-чего, то - что):  Нельзя найти того, чего нет.

Comment: _Vera: Похожие предложения:
1) **приместоименно-изъяснительные** ("вмещающие", для связи используются союзы/союзные слова): **Обещал (что?), что поможет**._ === 
 

В предложении _"Обещал, что поможет"_ **нет местоимений**, и потому придаточное не может быть названо  _**приместоименно**-изъяснительным._ 

Имеем просто **изъяснительное** придаточное.

Comment: Да, верно, местоименный коррелят для таких предложений  обязателен. Пример исправлен.

Answer (score 2):

> Надо отталкиваться наверное от глаголов *воображал* и *подумать*... Придаточные дополнительные?

Сейчас такие придаточные называют **придаточными изъяснительными**. В приведённых Вами предложениях ***будто*** синонимично ***что***.